# How to test localization in my app

Tags: ios, localization, xib

I am looking for the fastest most straightforward way to manually generate a string file and test its localization in another language. I have only one string to test with a key like so:

```
"KEY1" = "apple"
```

and I have subclassed an `IBDesignable` to have a property called `localizedKey` and then have overridden `drawRect` :

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // localization related
    if (self.localizedKey) self.text = NSLocalizedString(self.localizedKey, nil);
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

So I have to manually create the `.strings` file because I don't have string literals in code to use. How can I manually create the `lproj` and `.strings` file for another language (say English + Spanish) to test my design?

Answer (score 0):

In your Project settings, Under the "Info" Tab you can find Localizations. Click on the plus there to add a new language. Xcode will then ask you which files you would like to localize.

[image]